# What is the difference between propositional language LP and its dialect LP(σ)?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I’m reading through Mathematical Logic by Ian Chiswell and Wilfred Hodges. They talk about, and construct the rules for, $LP$ - which they call ‘the language of propositions’. The construction is done through the use of parsing trees.

In constructing $LP$, they say we need to choose a signature $\sigma$, which is a set containing symbols that can be used to stand for statements. I’m confused when they state:

> “For each choice of signature $\sigma$ there is a dialect $LP(\sigma)$ of $LP$.”

I don’t understand what they mean by ‘dialect’. I’ve tried looking it up, but haven’t found anything. What is the difference between the language $LP$ and the dialect $LP(\sigma)$? If choosing a signature $\sigma$ gives us $LP(\sigma)$, then it seems we don’t need it to construct $LP$ - just the dialect $LP(\sigma)$.

In a later definition they state:

> “The *formulas* of $LP(\sigma)$ are the formulas associated to parsing trees of $LP(\sigma)$. A *formula* of $LP$ is a formula of $LP(\sigma)$ for some signature $\sigma$.

They define what it means for something to be a formula for $LP(\sigma)$, but not what it means to be a formula of $LP$. The book defines parsing trees for $LP(\sigma)$, but it doesn’t define what a parsing tree for $LP$ would be. Likewise, the book defines the “lexicon” of $LP(\sigma)$ and what an “expression” of $LP(\sigma)$ is, but neither the lexicon of $LP$, nor what an expression of $LP$ would be, are defined.

If I made a guess, I’d say the language $LP$ is the same as the dialect $LP(\sigma)$, but where all possible symbols are allowed to be used as propositional symbols, while $LP(\sigma)$ restricts the possible propositional symbols to those in the set $\sigma$. Is this correct, and if so is this the only difference between them?

Comment: The way I would interpret it is that you need a signature before you even start writing sentences. $LP$ is the family consisting of all the $LP(\sigma)$'s for any given $\sigma.$ It's not $LP(\Sigma)$ where $\Sigma$ represents all possible symbols that could occur in a signature.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Does that mean $LP$ is not a language itself?

Comment: See page 32 : "The first step in constructing LP is to choose a set of symbols that can stand for statements. We call this set the *signature*."

Comment: Thus, a signature $\sigma_1$ will Be $\{ p,q,r,\}$, another one will be $\{ p_0, p_1, \ldots \}$ and so on.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I’m still not entirely sure what difference there is between $LP$ and $LP(\sigma)$. Is $LP(\sigma)$ just notation that indicates the signature we’ve chosen, and nothing more? And what is meant when the book states “A formula of $LP$ is a formula of $LP(\sigma)$ for some $\sigma$”?

Comment: I think that last quote encapsulates pretty well the relationship the authors have in mind. If we have one signature $\sigma_1=\{p_1,p_2,\ldots\}$ and another $\sigma_2=\{q_1,q_2,\ldots\},$ then $p_1\land p_2$ and $q_1\lor q_2$ are both formulas of LP, whereas only the first is of $LP(\sigma_1)$ and the second of $LP(\sigma_2).$ So we have a general notion of a propositional formula and a more specific one for when we’ve specified the signature we are using.

Comment: IMO, in the context of propositional calculus, the concept of *signature* is quite useless. It is basic, instead, in FOL. Thus, my conjecture is that the authors want to introduce it from the start...